# Output polygon data from postGIS and read it on Google Maps API

Tags: postgis, google-maps, postgresql, kml, google-maps-api

So, I have a group of polygons stored in PostGIS. I'm trying to build a web application with Google Base maps (using Google Maps API). Now, How do i output the polygons in the right format so that Google Maps API can read it?

I know about ST_Askml which outputs the data as KML, but what is the Google Maps function to read a kml on the fly? Or is there an alternative to outputting it as kml? Can i pull out the co-ordinates of each point on a polygon and load it onto the API on the fly?

Comment: Google Map v3  API can use JSON Examples: https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps

Comment: It's Brilliant :). Successful conversion! Thank you!

Comment: @Mapperz, your comment should be answer. This question is *"de facto"* answered and accepted, should be also *"de database"* :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment to Answer

Google Map v3 API can use JSON Examples: [github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps](https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps) – Mapperz♦ Apr 18 at 13:54