# Draw postgis geometries in google maps api

Tags: postgis, java, google-maps-api

Postgis have a base with a table of data lines and other points. 
I'm doing a java applet to query these tables and space to draw on google maps. 
My question is: what better way to spend these geometries to google maps? When I give the select the bank which is the best format to return the geomtrias to draw on the map, I had thought of GeoJSON. 
Does anyone have any example code or article addressing postgis + google maps api?

Comment: Have you tried searching the GIS SE for similar questions? Here are some that look relevant: [How to display a PostGIS table on Google Maps?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/how-to-display-a-postgis-table-on-google-maps) and [Output polygon data from postGIS and read it on Google Maps API](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/output-polygon-data-from-postgis-and-read-it-on-google-maps-api).

Comment: Surely you know of ST_GeomFromKML() http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html?

Comment: Sim eu testei ágora função ST_AsKML mas Localidade: Não Retorna nada e Localidade: Não Dá Erro. ``SELECIONE ST_AsKML (geom) DE ONDE myTable Cod = '214-2 '``